# On exporting Org-agenda to Google Calender via online ics file

Tags: org-mode, calendar, ical

I would like to apply the steps in:
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html

I am starting with updating my Org-mode entries in my Google calender.

However, to have an ics file online for Google calender automatic update, I tried to publish the file through MEGAsync as a shared file/directory and supplying the link to Google, which did not work (Google complaining about no ics file).

My goal is to automate the export (eventually cron-job) from Org to ics and the update on the online server and just wait for Google to update it (once a day is Okay for me).

So any help is appreciated!